# add identifier column

Tags: r, identifier

For example, my data looks like this:

```
Number Value
1       3
2       4
3       6
4       7
```

I want to add a third column as identifier column based on Value. If the value is >5, then group 1, otherwise group 2. Then return sth like this:

```
Number Value  Group
1       3      2
2       4      2
3       6      1
4       7      1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't tried anything, you could look up `ifelse()` in the R help.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new column to data frame:

```
df$Group <- ifelse(df$Value > 5, 1, 2)
```

I recommend reading more about `?data.frame` `?ifelse` and other data frame operations like
`?transform`